# Equivalents of KonvaJS filter values

Tags: javascript, css, konvajs, konvajs-reactjs

I'm trying to find KonvaJS filter values' equivalents of CSS filters on https://www.cssfilters.co/

For example how can I apply "1977" filter with KonvaJS. I tried many options but I'm getting different results everytime. Also is it possible to give values for Sepia or Grayscale?

I'm using filters like this (with different values):

```
backgroundImage.filters([
    Konva.Filters.Contrast,
    Konva.Filters.Brighten,
    Konva.Filters.HSV
    ]);

backgroundImage.contrast(10);
backgroundImage.brightness(0.10);
backgroundImage.saturation(7.8);           
backgroundImage.hue(0);
backgroundImage.value(0);
```

Comment: Can you show what did you try? Like a code sample?

Comment: @lavrton added some code to question and also is it possible to give values for sepia and grayscale like in this css filter generator?

Comment: @lavrton do you have any suggestion for that?

Answer (score 0):

I just made this combination of properties and it works very close:

```
  image.filters([
    Konva.Filters.Contrast,
    Konva.Filters.Brighten,
    Konva.Filters.HSV
    ]);

  image.contrast(10);
  image.brightness(0.1);
  image.saturation(1.1);           
  image.hue(0);
  image.value(0);


  const overlay = new Konva.Rect({
    width: image.width() * image.scaleX(),
    height: image.height() * image.scaleY(),
    fill: 'rgba(243, 106, 188, 0.3)',
    globalCompositeOperation: 'screen'
  });
  layer.add(overlay);
  layer.draw();
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/cuyikeduza/2/edit?html,js,output

If it is hard for you to adjust Konva filters and make sense to write your own filter.

Comment: thank you very much, is there any way to use values for Sepia too? for example for "Brannan" filter on cssfilters.co